# Spy method in react component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, mobx-react

My component has a method ..

```
onUpdateProperty = (key, value) => {
  this.state.formData[key] = value;
}
```

I want to test if after change input, this method is called...

```
it('on update input should update formData', function () {
  const wrapper = mount(<MyComp.wrappedComponent {...this.minProps} />);
  const spy = spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'onUpdateProperty');

  expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

  const nameInput = wrapper.find('[name="name"]');
  nameInput.simulate('change', {
    target: { name: 'name', value: 'v1' },
  });

  wrapper.update();

  // expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('name', 'v1');
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

> **wrappedComponent** is because I use Mobx-react

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My advice is to not spy of internal functions of your component but just test the `state`.

```
expect(wrapper.state.formData.name).toBe('v1)
```

if you really want to spy on it you have to spy on the prototype of you component.

```
jest.spyOn(MyComp.wrappedComponent.prototype, 'onUpdateProperty')
```